# Why is socket.io not emitting to everyone within a room?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

We are creating a multiplayer quiz app that uses socket.io and React. We have got a create room and join room working, but when the host in the lobby starts the game only they progress to the question page, and no one else in the lobby goes anywhere.

This is our code in app.js

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const URL = "http://localhost:3001"
```

```
const {
        difficulty,
        category,
        socket,
        setSocket,
        setAllPlayers,
        setUserData
    } = useContext(QuizContext)
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        const newSocket = io(URL)
        newSocket.on("update_room", (users) => {
            setAllPlayers(users);
            setUserData(prev => {
                return {...prev, room: users[0]?.room}
            });
        }); 
    }, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if(socket) {
            socket.on("game_started", () => {
                console.log(2);
                navigate("/quiz")
            });
        }
    }, [socket]);
```

This is the code in WaitingRoom.js

```
<button onClick={startQuiz}>Start</button
```

```
const startQuiz = () => {
    
        socket.emit("start_quiz", { room: userData.room, data: userData.data });
    };
```

This is the code in our backend on socketEvents/index.js

```
socket.on("start_quiz", ({ room, data }) => {
        users = users.map((user) => {
            return { ...user, data };
        });
        io.to(room).emit("game_started", users);
    });
```

We've looked at all the socket.io documentation and can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Is `room` defined?

Comment: https://github.com/Brendan-Geoghegan/Lap3_Project  -  Frontend
https://github.com/Ahmed78613/multiplayer-quiz-backend  -  Backend
Here are the repos for the project